# Usage of non public classes in spring java-based config

Tags: java, spring

It seems to be a simple question but yet i couldn't find clear answer while searching documentation and forums. I'm migrating from xml to java-based config (Spring 5.1.9). Due to some legacy restrictions in xml config i need to create a bean from some side library's non public class:

SampleClass.class

```
package side.library

class SampleClass {
 //... some code here
}
```

context.xml

```
...
<bean id = "sampleId" class "side.library.SampleClass">
...
```

And this works fine since Spring uses reflection inside and it creates bean without any problems at compile/runtime, but in java-based config usage of such class leads to an access error:

```
package my.configuration;

import side.library.SampleClass; // 'side.library.SampleClass' is not public in 'side.library'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

@Configuration
public class JavaConfiguration{

 @Bean
 public SampleClass sampleClass() {
  return new SampleClass(); // same error text
 }

}
```

So, what is the proper way to deal with this sutiation? Using reflection libs in @Configuration class to reach this class seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: can you try to create a package with the same name and put `JavaConfiguration` there?

Comment: Post the exact error message, not a summary of it.

Comment: Added exact error message. About creating package with the same name - it is not an option in my case, because packages named according to company's policies and i can't change it on my level.

Answer (score 1):

just a workaround: create a wrapper class in the outer project in the same package and use this class in your configuration.

```
package com.legacy;
public class Wrapper {

  private LegacyImpl legacyImpl;
  public Wrapper()
   this.legacyImpl = new LegacyImpl();
  }

  public void wrappedMethod() {
    this.legacyImpl.wrappedMethod();
  }
}
```